# Project transferring on SO?

Tags: support

Just came across this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753219/save-the-bible-project

I am unsure on how to close this properly.

I marked it as off topic and wrote:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site does
>   not offer project transferring services.

Or should I have closed it some other way?
[image]

Comment: This is just spam.

Answer (score 7):

It's simply off-topic, the question isn't related to a specific programming problem and is basically asking to refer a resource - which is one of the close reasons.